# selector for xpath / css subclass

Tags: xpath

I have an HTML document with a structure like this:

```
<div class="parent">
  <!--more stuff here-->
    <div class="child">
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to select the element with the class of `'child'` that sits beneath class `'parent'`.  Will the below get the job done in xpath, and/or are there better ways?  (Note that any number of elements can sit between the `<div>`s above.)

```
//div[@class='parent']//div[@class='child']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you meant to select all elements having class of `child` at any depth within `parent`, for example :

```
<div class="parent">
  <!--more stuff here-->
    <div class="child">
    </div>
    <div class="other">
        <div class="child">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

..then yes, your current XPath will do, both `child` in above sample will be selected. Or in case you only want *direct childs* of parent you can use single slash :

```
//div[@class='parent']/div[@class='child']
```